# How to Integrate Facebook

Tags: weblogic, portal

How to Integrate facebook to my portal(weblogic) application.

Thanks 
rj

Comment: You probably need to be more specific

Comment: Either use a 301 redirect to facebook.com or provide more specific information

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a [Wiki for developers](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Main_Page) who want to do everything by themselves from the ground up.

To be honest though, all the Facebook's API:s suck so don't expect this to be a breeze, even comparing the Facebook API:s to a rocky road would be a compliment of the highest magnitude.